# WebView apps and rejections

Tags: android, ios, iphone, mobile, webview

This is my first time on StackOverflow, so I come with two questions at the same time because they are related :

1 - I have a website that works great on my local server. It is made on Joomla. I heard about the "WebView" thing that iPhone and Android offer and I would like to know if it is possible, still in 2015/2016 to make an app that is basically just a WebView of a website ?

2 - If yes, I saw on old forums (earliest 2014) that Apple rejects WebView apps. Is it still the case nowadays, is there any "tricks" I should know about it ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes you can make the WebView only app but it should be mobile responsive
2. No apple don't reject the app with only webview in it but the website should be mobile responsive and you have to  fill all other info to approve it(I know because I have few apps with webview only).

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, I really appreciate it ! 
Yes the website is responsive. Now, we agree that in fact the WebView can in fact display a website already hosted on a server ? Basically display a website from a URL ?

Comment: Yes, at the time of approval website should look like an app and should be as it describes it the apple app approval form.

Comment: @Varun :  Can you let me know for these days era for Webview app for iOs, is It still approved or rejected, Some people told me only webview based app got rejected from apple.

Comment: @NeerajDubey I didn't tried app with webview only recently but I don't think that Apple can reject these app because if Apple do so then App hybrid(Html based eg, cordova, phonegap) app will be rejected

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have any knowledge for iOS but I can tell you about android one:
In android devices you can open a web site through 2 different ways, the first one is through web browser and the second one is the one you mentioned web view. Web view is a system component for Android OS that allows your application to display content from the web page directly inside it (the application).
Yes it is still available for Android you can make one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, that is already a part of the solution because I would also like to publish it on Android!